# Excel userform to create a summary line after adding variable amount of lines

Tags: vba, excel, userform

UPDATED TO ADD NEW CODE !

I have so far created a Userform that allows me to enter between 1 and 10 rows to my Excel spreadsheet based on how many different test results are entered into the user form. This is the code that I have which accomplishes that.

```
Set ws = Sheets("Master")
Dim NextRow As Long

NextRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count).End(x1Up).Offset(1, 0).Row

With Worksheets("Master").Range("A1")
    .Offset(NextRow, 0).Value = Me.txtTestDate.Value
    .Offset(NextRow, 1).Value = Me.txtSpraybox.Value
    .Offset(NextRow, 2).Value = Me.txtRanch.Value
    .Offset(NextRow, 3).Value = Me.txtFieldBox.Value
    .Offset(NextRow, 4).Value = Me.txtCommbox.Value
    .Offset(NextRow, 5).Value = Me.txtVarietybox.Value
    .Offset(NextRow, 6).Value = "Countries"
    .Offset(NextRow, 8).Value = "US"
    .Offset(NextRow, 9).Value = "Europe"
    .Offset(NextRow, 10).Value = "Japan"
    .Offset(NextRow, 11).Value = "Canada"
    .Offset(NextRow, 12).Value = "Taiwan"
    .Offset(NextRow, 13).Value = "NZ"
    .Offset(NextRow, 14).Value = "S. Korea"
    .Offset(NextRow, 15).Value = "CX"
    .Offset(NextRow, 16).Value = "RU"
    .Offset(NextRow, 17).Value = "Hong"
    .Offset(NextRow, 18).Value = "Singapore"
    .Offset(NextRow, 19).Value = "Indonesia"
    .Offset(NextRow, 20).Value = "UK"
    .Offset(NextRow, 21).Value = "Germany"
    .Offset(NextRow, 22).Value = "Brazil"
    .Offset(NextRow, 23).Value = "Thailand"
    .Offset(NextRow, 24).Value = "Mexico"
    .Offset(NextRow, 25).Value = "Aus"



    If Me.cboChem <> "" Then
        .Offset(NextRow + 1, 6).Value = Me.cboChem.Value
        .Offset(NextRow + 1, 7).Value = Me.txtResultbox.Value
    End If

    If Me.cboChem2 <> "" Then
        .Offset(NextRow + 2, 6).Value = Me.cboChem2.Value
        .Offset(NextRow + 2, 7).Value = Me.txtResultbox2.Value
    End If
    If Me.cboChem3 <> "" Then
        .Offset(NextRow + 3, 6).Value = Me.cboChem3.Value
        .Offset(NextRow + 3, 7).Value = Me.txtResultbox3.Value
    End If
    If Me.cboChem4 <> "" Then
        .Offset(NextRow + 4, 6).Value = Me.cboChem4.Value
        .Offset(NextRow + 4, 7).Value = Me.txtResultbox4.Value
    End If
    If Me.cboChem5 <> "" Then
        .Offset(NextRow + 5, 6).Value = Me.cboChem5.Value
        .Offset(NextRow + 5, 7).Value = Me.txtResultbox5.Value
    End If
    If Me.cboChem6 <> "" Then
        .Offset(NextRow + 6, 6).Value = Me.cboChem6.Value
        .Offset(NextRow + 6, 7).Value = Me.txtResultbox6.Value
    End If
    If Me.cboChem7 <> "" Then
        .Offset(NextRow + 7, 6).Value = Me.cboChem7.Value
        .Offset(NextRow + 7, 7).Value = Me.txtResultbox7.Value
    End If
    If Me.cboChem8 <> "" Then
        .Offset(NextRow + 8, 6).Value = Me.cboChem8.Value
        .Offset(NextRow + 8, 7).Value = Me.txtResultbox8.Value
    End If
    If Me.cboChem9 <> "" Then
        .Offset(NextRow + 9, 6).Value = Me.cboChem9.Value
        .Offset(NextRow + 9, 7).Value = Me.txtResultbox9.Value
    End If
    If Me.cboChem10 <> "" Then
        .Offset(NextRow + 10, 6).Value = Me.cboChem10.Value
        .Offset(NextRow + 10, 7).Value = Me.txtResultbox10.Value
    End If
End With
```

Now, I would like to add a Summary line inserted after the last filled line each time that "OK" is pressed. I have been researching for the last 3 days and haven't really been able to find anything that will accomplish what I want. I also have seen other ways to accomplish what I have already done (I know it's not the best way to do what I want) that look like they would be better ways to do it, but I always get error messages when I try other ways.

I was hoping to use something like:

```
NextRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row + 1
ws.Cells(NextRow, 4).Value = "Overall"
```

But it does not place it consistently at the end of the list. I also have been having trouble getting that form of code to work for all of the entries, but I am going to go back and try now, since I just got that code to run without giving an "Object needed" type of error message. I have also been getting `Error 1004`.

I don't have very much background coding knowledge but I have been doing my best to learn as much as I can as I go. Any explanation of what each line does/why it's better than what I have, would be greatly appreciated.

Not related to this question, but is it possible to write code that would allow the `userform` to read the conditional formatting of the cells after the results are entered and to give a yes/no response to it? For example, I have formatted my table to change to red or green based on each column's limits per the result in a separate column, but sometimes 4-5 rows are part of each test, therefore, I want an overall pass/fail row at the end of each "test" that is entered per the user form.

Answer (score 1):

To put it in the last row change:

```
NextRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row + 1
```

to:

```
NextRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
```

The `.Offset(1,0)` is taking care of making sure it's on the line below the final line of data, so `+1` isn't necessary.

Comment: When I use that code, I get a runtime error '1004' Application defined or object defined error.

Comment: Where do you declare `NextRow` and what is it declared as?

Comment: In each instance where it says RowCount above, I replaced it with NextRow and the code that you suggested.